# StreamProvider doesn't update list (Firestore)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I've created collection in Firestore called `users` and added several documents in it.
In Flutter's main, I've initialised `StreamProvider`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider(create: (_) => Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<UserStore>(create: (_) => UserStore()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and in my Widget, I want to see how many documents (users) i've in my collection

```
 StreamProvider<List<User>>.value(
                value: streamUsers(), child: Text("${Provider.of<List<User>>(context).length}")),
```

My streamUsers method is as follows (mapping documents to list of documents)

```
Stream<List<User>> streamUsers() {
        var ref = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
        return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.documents.map((doc) => User.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
    }
```

There is an obvious issue, that `Provider.of<List<User>>..` cannot be used like this. Also in the `StreamProviders` initialisation, I believe I miss my model type, but I couldn't understand how can I put there `List<User>`because it required to be type of `QuerySnapshot`

```
StreamProvider<List<User>>(create: (_) => Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots())
```

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

..aand I found the solution.

First, for creating a `StreamProvider` we do like this

```
StreamProvider<List<User>>(create: (_) => streamUsers()),
```

`streamUsers` method as follows

```
Stream<List<User>> streamUsers() {
    var ref = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
    return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.documents.map((doc) => User.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
  }
```

Then in our UI widget we simply call Provider to get any value from our data set (`List<User>`). In this case - only length.

```
Text("${Provider.of<List<User>>(context).length}")
```

Now everything updates automatically once any data changes are made.

Comment: If this the solution, you can accept your own answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks, @Blasanka. There is a two day window until I can accept my own answer.
Merry Christmas!